# Javascript event handler for Facebook Send

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm integrating the Facebook Send button to our site and I'm trying to run some javascript as soon as the user sends the page to someone. With the Facebook Like button you can subscribe via javascript to the `edge.create` event which fires when the user Likes the page. Is there an equivalent for the Facebook Send button? I tested it and the `edge.create` doesn't catch the Send button.

So basically, is there any javascript event handler for the Facebook Send button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you're looking for is "message.send" according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I was originally looking at the documentation for both the subscribe events (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and for the Like button (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and neither one mentions this event. I hate it when companies make it painful to find the correct documentation. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add your own listeners by directly subscribing them to the classes prototype.

For example, we use this to reposition the Like/Send menus accordingly once rendered:

```
        var Like = FB.CLASSES['XFBML.Like'];
        Like.prototype.subscribe('xd.presentEdgeCommentDialog', function(a){

            setTimeout(function(){
              var el = $('#like-btn > span.fb_edge_comment_widget');
                    // console.log(a);
                    // console.log(el);
                    el.css('left', '-200px');
                    el.css('top', '20px');
            }, 500);
        })
```

The exact events you can subscribe depend on the class. You'll need to research this by looking to the JS SDK and then backtracking which events are being fired.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, have you tried to add a function that looks for the send button and adds your own click listener to it when it gets added?

You won't be able to get any information like response.session, but you can tally how many people click the button.

I can see why they didn't include anything to subscribe to with FB.event.subscribe. When they like your page, connect elements on your page are populated with their information when the page reloads (you may reload the page in your method that gets fired). They can send your page to someone without liking you.

Comment: I tried adding an event handler manually like you mentioned but unfortunately since their XFBML translates to an iframe, it violates browser security to access the elements within the iframe. So unfortunately I don't think it's possible, but if you know of a trick to do that please let me know because that would be awesome.